# How to add another line of text below each radio button?

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]

My requirment is that,  I want to one text line below to the each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using slds radio group. Add onchange event on input tag and get the values accordingly

Html  :

```
<template>
    <div class="app slds-p-around_x-large">
        <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
            <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Radio Group Label</legend>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <span class="slds-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-61" value="radio-61" name="default" checked="" />
      <label class="slds-radio__label" for="radio-61">
        <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">Radio Label One</span>
                </label>
                </span>
                <span>Radio Label One Text</span>
                <span class="slds-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-62" value="radio-62" name="default" />
      <label class="slds-radio__label" for="radio-62">
        <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">Radio Label Two</span>
                </label>
                </span>
                <span>Radio Label Two Text</span>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</template>
```

Result :

[image]